# How to recover data from an un-bootable SSD or make it boot?

Tags: windows-10, boot, data-recovery

I got a new NVME PCIE SSD yesterday. After installing it to my Acer nitro an515-53 laptop, I wanted to move all my stuff over to it. After cloning all the partitions, the computer complained that "a required device isn't connected or can't be accessed." I tried re-cloning the partitions with different software, and then it booted just fine. Then I deleted the data off the original hard drive to make space. To test how fast my SSD was, I rebooted. Then I got the same error.

[image]

I doubt that my data is gone, but it isn't bootable. How can I fix this? I have a thumb drive with the windows installer/recovery image on it. So far, I've tried a lot of bcdedit commands that didn't work, sfc /scannow, StartRep.exe, switching the sata mode from RST with optane to AHCI and back, and more, but maybe I just haven't done the right combination of these things.

My HDD (now empty) is mounted on C: when booting into recovery mode and the SSD is on D:. The partitions on the SSD are: System, Reserved, Primary, Recovery, Recovery. The D:\boot directory is empty but other than that D: contains normal-looking Windows files.

Comment: Try to reinstall Windows 10. In the installation process Windows should detect the existing installation and allow to keep all user data and installed programs.

Comment: If you are VERY concerned about the data on that drive, there are external NVMe drive cases that will help you copy the data off before you start messing with the drive.  I just saw them for as little as $20 USD.  You might want to recover before running windows setup against it if the data is important to you.

Comment: I backed up some of the important-ish data to the HDD, hopefully Windows gives me the option @Robert mentioned when installing..

Comment: It says if I want to keep the old stuff then I have to not use the thumb drive, but it expects Windows to start normally with that option which it won't, I have to use the thumb drive.